# How to read serialized files?

Tags: java, file, serializable

This in Java as well.  I can't seem to get this method to work, the saving part works great and saves the object. But once I try to read the file it doesn't work and I get `ObjectInputStream` errors. I'm new to using the `Serializable` interface and none of the other questions seem to help me.  The expected output is `name Joe, weight 153, height 69`.  The errors are:

java.io.InvalidClassException: Person; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1404541419531259795, local class serialVersionUID = 3020781085877336930
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)

```
    public static boolean save(Person p, String filename) {
        try {
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(filename));
        os.writeObject(p);
        os.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

    public static Person read(String filename) {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                filename));
        Object o = oi.readObject();
        oi.close();
        if (o instanceof Person)
            return (Person) o;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Do you want to save or load?");
    String option = s.next();
    Person p = new Person("Joe", 154, 69);
    if (option.equals("save")) {
        if (save(p, "newfile")) {
            System.out.println("Saved.");
        }
    }
    if (option.equals("load")) {
        Person p1 = read("newfile");
        if ((p1 != null)) {
            System.out.println(p1.getInfo());
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What language are you using? I am assuming Java?

Comment: You should tag it Java and mention it in your post. It will get better traction and attention.

Comment: yes I just did thank you though

Comment: Where do the errors occur? I also notice you're not closing your stream.

Comment: The errors occur at Object o = oi.readObject(); and  Person p1 = read("newfile"); and yeah I just closed it now thanks

Comment: Show the error, and show a compilable version of the code that includes the write side. You may be writing the file incorrectly.

Comment: There we go, I'm pretty sure the writing part is fine but not 100 percent sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce  **serialVersionUID** to the **Person** class as described in [What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)

it seems that you have changed your Person class somehow, and now you can not read the saved version because the bytecode has been changed.